# How to test require js code using Jasmine?

Tags: jquery, testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am working on requireJs in my current project in Magento 2. In that I need to write custom javascript components or files. How can I test any javascript file with Jasmine ?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to be testing primarily through the browser, or will you have access to a nodejs instance to run your tests on?

Comment: I have nodejs instance to test it.

Comment: Ok, so what have you already tried?